Белая вертикальная полоса справа, на мобильной версии сайта
https://kovriginleonid.github.io/Chess/
Я уже перепробовал все предлагаемые методы, настроил мета viewport, везде добавил
overflow-x: hidden;, перепроверил не выпадают ли какие либо блоки, назначив глобальный бордер в 1px. Но совершенно не понимаю откуда она берётся.

P.S. Всевозможные принудительные расширения html и body до 100vw хотелось бы избежать, из за особенностей того, как сделано изображение для header. Но если нет другого варианта, как можно собрать этот коллаж таким образом, что бы всё оставалось на своих местах ?

у вас в @media (max-width: 768px) указано max-width: 375px;

Требование было pixel perfect, по макету. Разве он не должен скалироваться, что бы занять всю ширину экрана ? Это второй мой проект, я ещё совсем зелёный, так что даже в базовых вопросах могу теряться.

Разве он не должен скалироваться, что бы занять всю ширину экрана - нет, не должен. pixel perfect - работает только тогда, когда все размеры явно заданы. Если в макете ширина 375 - для любой другой ширины pixel perfect не получится, если нет соответствующего макета

у вас одинаковые значения в минимальной и максимальной ширине
@media (max-width: 768px)
body {
    max-width: 375px;
    min-width: 375px;
}

max-width поменяйте на 100% к примеру или 100vw
